# Can we write class inside VBScript function?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

```
Function CWSLogin(strApplicationPath,strUser,strMember,strPassword)

    Class TryCatchFinally

         Private Sub Class_Initialize 'Try

         End Sub

    End Class

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Functions are in classes where they become known as methods.

Comment: Then how can i use try catch functionality inside function?

Comment: VBScript doesn't have try - catch. We use On Error Resume Next. So after every potential error `If err.number <> 0 then something:err.clear`